# Store data from multiple mysql table and sort according to there time

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch data from 3 tables suppose x,y,z both 3 table has common field timestamp. I want to sort data according to `timestamp`. How can I do this?

Comment: I just want logic of that.whether i use mysql query or i used array to store all table info and then sort it accordingly.please give us fast way of fetching data..

Comment: please provide table structure and some sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY in your query to sort the current result set using a column. Using DESC and ASC you can change the order of the sorting.

Please refer to [MySQL 5.0 Reference - Sorting rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) for more information and Examples.